# Hard drive partiton problem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, resize, boot-partition

I want to partition my hard drive so my data doesn't get deleted when I change operating system. But I get this error:

[image: sudo fdisk /dev/sda error]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include either screenshots showing the error or the exact error message? It would also help to know which version of Ubuntu you are running. This will make it more likely that you will receive a response 

Comment: can't figure how to add image to the post

Comment: [This wiki document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition) outlines how to resize a partition using GParted. You will need to do this from your Installation USB (or DVD) because a partition cannot be resized if it is currently mounted 

Comment: Please don't attach screenshots; rather, paste the text to the question, formatted as code (with a line consisting of 3 backticks before and after: ```).

Comment: OK. so I need to resize sda5 to free space for the next partition first then create a partition in this free space? Then if I reinstall os the data in this new partition not get deleted?

Answer (score 1):

The existing partitions already take up all the disk space, so you can't create another one.